# COUNT query on a boolean column with DQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a "simple" question whose answer seems not to be in the official DQL docs. 
Given an application built with Doctrine2, suppose to have a **boolean column** (let say *B* for entity *Foo*), how to count the number of rows such that the value in B is true (or false)?

PS: If may helps, I use MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to count the number of "true" values:

```
    'SELECT COUNT(f.B) as numtrue  
            FROM Foo f 
            WHERE f.B = TRUE'
```

To get the number of occurence of "false" values:

```
    'SELECT COUNT(f.B) as numfalse  
            FROM Foo f 
            WHERE f.B = FALSE'
```